# Creating buttons inside a class with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a small tkinter app in python, and need to create a large amount of buttons, that all have attributes, so I decided to create them in a class, and then create lots of instances of the class. However, because the tkinter Button is already an object, I'm not too sure how the composition between the two classes will work. But currently, when I create an instance of my class, it seems to the the buttons command method, however will not run the command when clicked.

Below is my module for creating buttons, which I import into my main tkinter module, and create instances of. I wondered why the button command 'selectSeat' is run when creating the buttons, and why it doesn't run when the buttons are clicked.

```
from tkinter import *
class SeatButton():
    def __init__(self, master, row, seat):
    ''' Initalises a seating button '''
    self.colour = "green"
    self.state = "free"
    self.row = row
    self.seat = seat
    self.button = Button(master,bg=self.colour, command=self.selectSeat(), padx=10)


def update(self):
    ''' Updates the button's colour '''
    print("i shouldnt run")
    if self.state == "free":
        self.colour = "green"
    if self.state == "selected":
        self.colour = "blue"

def selectSeat(self):
    ''' Calculates what happens when a button is clicked'''
    # If the seat is avaliable, it is now selected
    print("hwey")
    if self.state == "free":
        self.state = "selected"
        self.colour = "blue"
    elif self.state == "selected":
        self.state == "free"
        self.colour = "green"
```

Comment: You are calling the method directly in 'command=self.selectSeat()'. Just use 'command=self.selectSeat'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `command=self.selectSeat()`, the function `selectSeat` will be executed directly (on initialization).

Try passing only a reference (without braces):

```
self.button = Button(master, bg=self.colour, command=self.selectSeat, padx=10)
                                                                   ^^
```

Tkinter will then call the function itself, see [TKinter Callbacks](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) for more examples.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks, how would you pass in variables and such without parameters?

Comment: Have you tried extending the Tkinter button? Like `class SeatButton(Button)` instead of a `self.button` attribute.